# Group specific entry from section

Tags: permissions, craft-features

Can this be done? I have a section called Bookings. I have 2 user groups A and B.

I would like both groups to have access to the section (bookings) but for some of the entries in the section, I would like to exclude one of the groups. Giving access to only A or B.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Craft doesn't have an entry-level (or even entry type-level) permissions system; it's only possible to define permissions for sections.

Of course, "anything" is possible with a custom [plugin](http://pluginfactory.io), but without knowing more about your use case (what's the criteria for excluding group A or B for a particular entry?) it's difficult to advise further.

If you can edit your question and elaborate on the use case/goal, I might be able to update this answer.

Comment: Here are a couple of related feature requests for more fine-grained permissions you might want to consider voting for too, @garyconstable. https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/11721282-field-level-permissions and https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/13630761-permissions-on-entry-type-level

Comment: The feature requests have been moved to here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/947 and here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/955